# Configuring Visual Studio 2019 to automatically pick up the highlighted option from intellisense in C++ by hitting enter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

The intro text says it all. I tried messing around with options related with the intellisense on VS, but no success. I mean, it does pick our options via enter, but, by the default, we gotta confirm the selection with the arrow keys first, which is an unnecessary step. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement your idea, you need to set `Member List Commit Aggressive` to true.

The specific path is Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Member List Commit Aggressive.

[image]